# Is there a true PS5 version of GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, version-differences, ps5

I purchased the remastered version of Grand Theft Auto 5 for the PS4 Pro. My question has two parts:

1. Is there *any* difference between the
   a) remastered version of GTA 5 for the PS4/PS4 Pro
   and a
   b) "PS5" GTA 5
2. If there is a difference, does my *owning* the PS4 remastered disc grant me access to this newer version (as opposed to my needing to make an additional purchase through the playstation store)?

I have read reports that seem to indicate that the PS5 version is, in fact, different, yet I seem unable to purchase any such a version of the game through the PS store, which leads me to believe that if there is a difference I have been automatically granted access to the newer version of the game.

Answer (score 7):

The PS5 version is called "GTA 5: Expanded & Enhanced Edition", and these are the improvements:

##### Single player

| **PS5** | **PS4** |
| --- | --- |
| Three graphical options, including 4K and 60 frames-per-second | 1080p, 30 frames-per-second |
| Seamless character switching | Longer loading times |
| Upgraded textures and draw distance | Standard textures and draw distance |
| Raytracing support in select graphical modes | No raytracing |
| HDR support | No HDR support |
| 3D audio support | Stereo audio |
| DualSense controller support with haptic feedback | Standard rumble feedback |
| Improved gameplay and controls | Standard gameplay and controls |

##### GTA Online

| **PS5** | **PS4** |
| --- | --- |
| Career Builder to help new players get started | No Career Builder |
| New main menu loading stream highlighting promoted content | Standard loading screen |
| Hao's Special Works for brand new, new-gen exclusive speed modifications | No speed improvement modifications |
| Hao's Special Works Time Trial events | No Hao's Special Works Time Trial events |
| Hao's Special Works Premium Test Ride | No Hao's Special Works Premium Test Ride |
| Upgraded textures and draw distance | Standard textures and draw distance |
| Raytracing support in select graphical modes | No raytracing |
| HDR support | No HDR support |
| 3D audio support | Stereo audio |
| DualSense controller support with haptic feedback | Standard rumble feedback |
| Improved gameplay and controls | Standard gameplay and controls |

Sources: [here](https://www.pushsquare.com/guides/gta-5-all-ps5-vs-ps4-differences) and [here](https://www.gtabase.com/news/grand-theft-auto-v/title-updates/gta-5-ps5-xbox-series-x-s-all-new-features-for-expanded-enhanced-edition).

It seems a different game, and not a simple upgrade you can do on you PS4 version.